# Connect iPod Touch to WiFi with hidden SSID

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi

is it possible to connect an iPod Touch to a WiFi network whose SSID is hidden? If so, how can this be achieved?

Regards,
Christoph

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the SSID is hidden, that means you don’t see the network’s name, so the only way to connect is by manually typing the SSID.

You have to select “Other” from the list of WiFi networks.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the screenshot, and for beating me to it by 15 seconds.

Comment: @cometbill turns out I had the iPhone already connected and charging, that probably made the difference :)

Answer (score 1):

My wireless home network SSID is hidden, for obvious reasons, when I used my iPod Touch for the first time, I manually entered the SSID name and passcode, but I could not get connected. I have to go into my wireless router and enable SSID, that was the only way I could connect my iPod Touch. The problem is when I turn the iPod Touch off, and turn it back on, the iPod touch still won't see my SSID, after it's hidden again.

Ex: if my iPod Touch is connected and I hid my SSID, no problem. When I turn my ipod off and on again, that's when it won't connect because my SSID is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > WiFi > Other

Enter the SSID of the hidden network

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue but leaving the SSID visible seems to take care of that.  The only real wireless security anyway is to have a MAC filter list so just go to settings on the IPOD and get it's MAC address to add to the filter list on your wireless router.

Comment: MAC filter lists actually add no security as MAC addresses are transmitted in plaintext even in WPA2.